# Show NodeJS Errors in main html file itself

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I made a form using NodeJs, i made some validations of input that show errors when user enter wrong values, the problem here is that the error appear on a new blank page but i need the error to appear on the main html file itself with cool styling
here's the live site http://mido.sundays.org.uk

I tried to make post request on the same route to see if the error will appear on the same page or not but the page turned to white blank page with the text inside

```js
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    const SchemaValidation = {
      name: joi.string().min(4).required().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'Name is required. (min:4 chars)',
          };
        }),
        email: joi.string().email().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'Email field can\'t be Empty',
          };
        }),
        phone: joi.string().min(8).max(14).required().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'Valid Phone number is Required (min:8 characters - max: 14 characters)',
          };
        }),
        university: joi.string().required().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'University Field is Required',
          };
        }),
        faculty: joi.string().required().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'Faculty Field is Required',
          };
        }),
        academicyear: joi.string().required().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'Academic Year Field is Required and should range from 1-6',
          };
        }),
        workshop: joi.array()
        .items(joi.string().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'You Should pickup 2 Committees',
          };
        })),
        first_choice: joi.string().required().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'You should pickup first choice',
          };
        }),
        second_choice: joi.string().required().error(() => {
          return {
            message: 'You should pickup second choice',
          };
        }),
    };

    joi.validate(req.body,SchemaValidation,(err, result) => {
      if(err) {
          res.send(`<p style='color:red; text-align:center; margin-top:20px;'>${err.details[0].message}</p>`);
          return; // don't try saving to db if the schema isnt valid
      }
      else
        res.send(`<p style='color:green; text-align:center; margin-top:20px;'>Successfully Posted Data</p>`);
    })
  });
```

All what i need is to show the error in the same page and prevent the submit..

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I highly racommand you to use Pug.js (Template Engine), because you can't pass parameters into a specific page. By using a template engine, you can pass data as object, and render them with res.render('index', {error: res.error.message}).

You will be able to output into the page from server side the error object displaying whatever you needed to display!

res.send('content') basically it's a document.write()

https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Comment: Well, you're right.. now i used swig template engine, it show the error in the same page but after reloading it.. i need to show the error without reloading the page.. is that possible?

Comment: Could you provide a code? I'm not so good at it, but I will try to help you!

Comment: `if(err) {
          res.render('index', {output: '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">${err.details[0].message}</div>'});
          return; // don't try saving to db if the schema isnt valid
      }` 
this is an example.. when it find error it reload the page and show the error on the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't do the validation on the front end before submitting the form? That is usually the preferred way. You can have some backend validation so that you don't get bad data into your db but once you send a request you need to send a response back and in your case the response is the message not the entire HTML page. You can create a validation by adding an event listener to your submit button then using Ajax once you validate to send the data to the backend or you can use Bootstrap's built in validation and not mess with Ajax just through the form action. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation